# Объясните, пожалуйста, что не так с изменением размера?

Tags: python, opencv, resize

Я пытаюсь масштабировать видеофайл из библиотеки [scikit-video](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/), но не могу разобраться в ошибке:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-9ed9b2a0d1f2> in <module>()
----> 1 src_video_example, tar_video_example = load_video_examples(vid_src=1)

1 frames
/scaleatt/video/utils/load_video_data.py in load_video_examples(vid_src, video_loaded)
     21     if vid_src == 1:
     22         src_video_example = skvideo.io.vread(skvideo.datasets.bigbuckbunny())
---> 23         src_video_example = scale_utils.scale_cv2(src_video_example, 1024, 1024)
     24 
     25         tar_video_example = skvideo.io.vread(skvideo.datasets.bikes())

/scaleatt/video/scaling/scale_utils.py in scale_cv2(xin, trows, tcols, alg)
     38 
     39 def scale_cv2(xin, trows, tcols, alg=cv2.INTER_CUBIC):
---> 40     res = cv2.resize(xin, (tcols, trows), interpolation=alg)
     41     return res

error: OpenCV(4.1.2) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/resize.cpp:3363: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !dsize.empty() in function 'resize'
```

Comment: Скорее всего что-то не так с исходником картинки, которую ресайзите, он точно не битый?

Comment: это видео файл: http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/datasets.html

Comment: Ок, а что такое `scale_utils.scale_cv2` - это откуда? У меня такое впечатление, что `opencv` умеет только с отдельными фреймами работать, а с видео в целом не умеет. А, это похоже ваш файл. В общем, где вы нашли примеры, что `opencv` умеет видео в целом ресайзить? Хотелось бы на них посмотреть. Насколько я понимаю, нужно разбирать видео на отдельные фреймы и каждый фрейм отдельно обрабатывать `opencv`.

Comment: Я тоже так думал, но skvideo.io.vread загружает любое видео (здесь bigbuckbunny) в память как один ndarray.